# Output image variable from php to html

Tags: php, html, web, web-deployment

I am learning web development. I am doing a project which takes screenshots of IP cameras and output the images in a user friendly webpage.

I have a php script which finds the latest image in a directory and creates a png image.

I also have a html file to use a test for the webpage.

I cannot seem to get the output for the image in php to be used in my html file.
In my html code below, I have hard coded images from the directory. This is where I need the image variable to be.

```
php output:
/////Create image from latest file/////

$imagepath = $path . $last_file; //Create full path string  -> (C:/xampp/htdocs/VideoWallTest/ + latest image filename)

//echo $imagepath; //Test message to show full filename
$image=imagecreatefrompng($imagepath); //create image from png

$imgheight=imagesy($image); //Set image height as height of original image

$color=imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); //Set color for image caption (white)

//Add text to image bottom
imagestring($image, 5, 100, $imgheight-50, "Test_VideoWall", $color); //Select where text will appear and properties
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Output
imagepng($image);
Html code:
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en-US"> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   
  <title>Cadillac Videowall Monitoring</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div class="wrap">

  <!-- Define all of the tiles: -->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="/VideoWallTest/12-30-14_2016-06-27.png" />
      <p><a href="http://localhost/VideoWallTest/">TEST 1</a><p>
      <div class="titleBox">1</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="/VideoWallTest/12-30-14_2016-06-27.png" />
      <p><a href="http://localhost/VideoWallTest/">TEST 2</a><p>
      <div class="titleBox">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="/VideoWallTest/12-30-14_2016-06-27.png" />
      <p><a href="http://localhost/VideoWallTest/">TEST 3</a><p>
      <div class="titleBox">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You cannot have the HTML and the image generation in the same php. You need to generate the image using `header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng($image);` in a separate php file

Comment: I have the HTML and PHP code in two different files. So will I create a new PHP file with that line?

Comment: No - your code is fine if it is not in the same file, It should work - try to call the image one from the command line to see any errors